# How can I fixed the size of height of my page even resizing vertically my browser in responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on my design when it comes to height. On the responsive width I have no problem but when I resize vertically my main content will push upward overlapping my header. How can I fixed the height of my page? Here is my styles:

```
#my-header {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

then

```
.my-content { /** no styles applied yet **/}
```

I tried adding margin-top to my-content but it adds up the margin top between header and my-content.

That's all I hope you can help me.

Comment: Are some of your elements positioned absolutely? Please add relevant code or create a fiddle

Comment: @ATomCalledStu The issue is on my banner height on my main page. Because I made my banner using `100vh` and after I added a `min-height: 1000px` it is now fixed. Is there any other solution that prevents the use of `min-height`? Or it is only the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue on my layout is the banner itself.

```
.hero-banner {
    background: url('my-banner-image.jpg') 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'proxima-soft', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 1000px; /** this fixed my issue **/
}
```

I forgot to mention the one that is overlapping is actually my text inside my banner.